# Unity3d Character failing to move horizontal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Maybe it is because if been trying to fix it for a few hours now.  But my character is not moving horizontaly.

First I was useing a cube as character to write it. When I replaced this cube with a player model it still moved up and down but not left and right anymore. Even after 2 hours of trying to figure it out I really couldnt stand it anymore and decided to post it on here.

Due to the long code I decided to paste it in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/iAsN51rW

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you by accident set a fixed x or y position on the object?

Comment: @skami At first i thought so aswel :) i found the answer. when switching to my model  the side it faced changed so it was just moveing into the depth and back makeing it look like it dident move ;)  after switching it finaly worked.... Was about time i found it .. took me almost 2,5 hours Xd;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. And just like I thought, When Switching to my player model I had to change the movement direction  from

```
transform.Translate(speed* Time.deltaTime,0,0);
```

to

```
transform.Translate(0,0,speed* Time.deltaTime);
```

As my cube was looking At the camera , But my player was looking towards the sides